# Ceramic Anchor Tips / Counter weights

Tags: electrical

My whirlpool electric range has three ceramic Anchor-Tip counterweights on the back. Looks like the fourth is missing as there is a place for it. Does it need the fourth?
Thanks

Comment: A model number could help here.

Comment: How about a picture?